# Remove file extensions in URLs

Tags: html, .htaccess

I need a help in .htaccess modification. 
I have an index.html , contact_us.html, about.html, faq.html (pages)
But I'd need a simple .htaccess rule to Override those .html extension. 
Like this,  instead of yoursite.com/contact_us.html  a user can still access your contact webpage using yoursite.com/contact_us

Even with or 
without the  .html extension. 
They can still get to the same page they meant to access.

Answer (score 0):

[Multiviews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
Options +Multiviews
```

This will also let you keep the same URLs if you later decide you'd rather be working with `index.pl` or `index.php`.

Comment: You said I should add 
{Options +Multiviews}
on my  .htaccess file to do the specific job . Alright that's fine.  But I don't even have any   .htaccess file. 
Please would you mind to   help me with the full custom  .htaccess that will do exactly what I want? 
Thanks in advance.